# array_unshift in multidimensional array insert at first element in all arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

first of all i say sorry for my english..

i have to insert a element in a multidimensional array at the first position on all the sub-array..

```
$docNum = "RT/2013-2014/0266";
$values = 
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2014-08-07
        [1] => Dl-Dis1
        [2] => Discount
        [3] => 7.500
        [4] => 26.25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2014-08-07
        [1] => Dl-Dis1
        [2] => Discount
        [3] => 7.500
        [4] => 24.38
    )

 )
```

these two are input..

code i give to combine is

```
array_unshift($values, $docNum);
```

and the output i have is

```
 Array
(
[0] => RT/2013-2014/0266
[1] => RT/2013-2014/0266
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2014-08-07
        [1] => Dl-Dis1
        [2] => Discount
        [3] => 7.500
        [4] => 26.25
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2014-08-07
        [1] => Dl-Dis1
        [2] => Discount
        [3] => 7.500
        [4] => 24.38
    )

)
```

the output i want should be

```
 Array
(


[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => RT/2013-2014/0266
        [1] => 2014-08-07
        [2] => Dl-Dis1
        [3] => Discount
        [4] => 7.500
        [5] => 26.25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => RT/2013-2014/0266
        [1] => 2014-08-07
        [2] => Dl-Dis1
        [3] => Discount
        [4] => 7.500
        [5] => 24.38
    )

)
```

i think hope you understand what i am asking..

and also i already see this [link]:(stackoverflow.com/questions/15398678/array-unshift-for-multidimensional-arrays)

pls dont mark as duplicate..

thank you advance..

Comment: Traverse and use array_unshift on the sub-arrays. Really nothing special to do.

Comment: thsnks for your comment u give a route to my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unshift it outright. That will prepend the values on the parent array not the sub arrays. You can loop it first, then each sub array, then you use unshift. Example:

```
// generate the string with the value you'd unshift
$docNum = "RT/2013-2014/0266";

// build up your multidimensional array
$values = array(
    array('2014-08-07', 'Dl-Dis1', 'Discount', 7.500, 26.25),
    array('2014-08-07', 'Dl-Dis1', 'Discount', 7.500, 24.38),
);

// for every sub-array...
foreach($values as &$sub_array) { // & reference
    // ... unshift your value
    array_unshift($sub_array, $docNum);
}

echo '<pre>';
// check out the result
print_r($values);
```

Output is as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => RT/2013-2014/0266
        [1] => 2014-08-07
        [2] => Dl-Dis1
        [3] => Discount
        [4] => 7.5
        [5] => 26.25
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => RT/2013-2014/0266
        [1] => 2014-08-07
        [2] => Dl-Dis1
        [3] => Discount
        [4] => 7.5
        [5] => 24.38
    )
)
```